# Linear algebra machinery for differentiation of families of functions.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, representation-theory, symbolic-computation

So I know that since differentiation is linear, for many types of functions we can represent it using linear algebra. Famous examples include polynomials, if we represent them with their coefficients stored in vectors. Such a matrix performing differentiation on 4th order polynomial could look like:

$$D(4) = \left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&2&0&0\\
0&0&0&3&0\\
0&0&0&0&4
\end{array}\right] \text{assuming order of coefficients stored as  }  \left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
x^0\\
x^1\\
x^2\\
x^3\\
x^4
\end{array}\right]$$

Other families of functions have other differential operators, the trigonometric functions are well known for this:

$$D_{sintrig} = \left[\begin{array}{rr}
0&1\\
-1&0
\end{array}\right] \text{assuming coefficients stored like} \left[\begin{array}{rr}
\sin\\
\cos
\end{array}\right]$$
and the hyperbolic trigs:
$$D_{hyptrig} = \left[\begin{array}{rr}
0&1\\
1&0
\end{array}\right] \text{assuming coefficients stored like} \left[\begin{array}{rr}
\sinh\\
\cosh
\end{array}\right]$$
Then we can go one step further, investigating what happens when we use chain rule. A famous example for this is the Hermite polynomials which are the polynomials resulting in iteratively differentiating the function $e^{-x^2}$ which is of the form $\exp(P(x))$. This also gives linear representations, although more complicated.

---

So finally, to my question... do there exist systematic approaches to build such differential linear algebra "machinery" for even more complicated families of functions?

Comment: It seems to me that all your examples concern finite dimensional subspaces of the set of differentiable functions invariant by the differentiation. In order to find such  subspaces what you need is to solve an homogeneus linear system of differentiable functions. You should check especially the matrix exponential method. For example, you can find here these methods.: http://www.math.utah.edu/~gustafso/2250systems-de.pdf

Comment: You have a very good point. Thanks for the link. In practice I am interested in any sequence of subspaces which can systematically build up ( "close enough" in some sense ) function of interest.